# Difference between operators in a URL

Tags: node.js, express, http, url, mongoose

What's the difference between using **:** and **?** in a URL? For example **/products/:id** and **/products?id=1**? I am trying to get the values from the URL like this `Product.findById (req.params.id)` but I was wondering which one is most suitable. I know using **:** do I have to use `req.params` and **?** `req.query` but I don't understand the difference between them, are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my point of view, it is totally different if you are using RESTFUL API pattern

`/products/:id` called path parameters

> The path parameters determine the resource you’re requesting for. Think of it like an automatic answering machine that asks you to press 1 for service, press 2 for another service, 3 for yet another service and so on.
>   Path parameters are part of the endpoint itself and are not optional

but query parameters

> Technically, query parameters are not part of the REST architecture, and they used to help you completely understand how to read and use API’s Query parameters give you the option to modify your request with key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Having your parameters in the query is conceptually optional to the router, query parameters are more of properties and descriptions of the request itself, like when saying *GET /users?sort=asc*, in this case, the *sort* attribute was more of a description to the request and the request could complete the fetch without it, that might not always be the case, but a query parameter still describes its request even if it was mandatory.

On the other hand, URL parameters are part of the request itself, the URL without the parameter doesn't make sense, like *GET /users/:userID*, in this case, not supplying *userID* will supply unexpected data (A list of users for example) if it didn't break the router completely. URL parameters play part in defining the request rather than just describing it, and they can't be optional.